# HTML label is not disappearing or moving up when there is an input

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

my html label tag isn't disappearing when there is an input.
it was working before adding validators, but still can't understand why it happened... Thank you for your help in case...
[image: You can see, the label isn't disappearing or moving up]

here is my html code:

```
<h1>Add a new course</h1>

{{#if error}}
  <p class="alert">{{error}}</p>
{{/if}}

<form action="/add" method="POST" novalidate>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input
      id="title"
      name="title"
      type="text"
      class="validate"
      required
      value="{{data.title}}"
    />
    <label for="title">title</label>
    <span class="helper-text" data-error="Enter the name"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field">
    <input
      id="price"
      name="price"
      type="number"
      class="validate"
      required
      min="1"
      value="{{data.price}}"
    />
    <label for="price">The price</label>
    <span class="helper-text" data-error="Enter the price"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field">
    <input
      id="img"
      name="img"
      type="text"
      class="validate"
      required
      value="{{data.img}}"
    />
    <label for="img">URL image</label>
    <span class="helper-text" data-error="Enter the url image"></span>
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

and here is my add.js file:

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const Course = require("../models/course");
const router = Router();
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
const { courseValidators } = require("../utils/validators");
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");
router.get("/", auth, (req, res) => {
  res.render("add", {
    title: "Add",
    isAdd: true,
  });
});

router.post("/", auth, courseValidators, async (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).render("add", {
      title: "Add",
      isAdd: true,
      errors: errors.array()[0].msg,
      data: {
        title: req.body.title,
        price: req.body.price,
        img: req.body.img,
      },
    });
  }

  const course = new Course({
    title: req.body.title,
    price: req.body.price,
    img: req.body.img,
    userId: req.user,
  });

  try {
    await course.save();
    res.redirect("/courses");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Please help me to solve it! it was working before, but it stopped working after addding validators...

here is CSS file:

```
.nav-wrapper {
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.price {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.course {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.course h1 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.course img {
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
}

.course .price.big {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.card-action.actions {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.course-form {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.auth {
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
.alert {
  padding: 0.5rem 1 rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background: rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: red;
}

.avatar {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: It can be css issue too. Can you share css for the classes mentioned ?

Comment: @Mahesh i updated the question and showed the css code

Comment: Is that all ? As I can see input-field class missing ?

Comment: Will it be possible to setup codesandbox and share just the sample code. I can guide you.

Comment: @mahesh that was working before adding validators

Comment: With the code as is, I dont see any issue. Can it be browser specific issue ?